# awk: exclude pattern, match only expression, sort, uniq

Tags: regex, bash, sorting, awk, uniq

I'm trying to process 500,000 lines of text. My code below works but seems incredibly insufficient, to me. I want to test this theory by accomplishing this with awk to see if I have any sort of time savings. This code block is replicated through out my script using various variables. A savings of time here would equate to 10 times the savings at end of script. However, I'm really struggling to achieve this with awk.

Script:

> ```
> _regex_ipv4_ip_='((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])'
>
> _regex_ipv4_cidr_='(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))'
>
> grep -v '^#' ${tmp}/url_* | grep -Eho "${_regex_ipv4_ip_}|${_regex_ipv4_cidr_}" | sort | uniq >${tmp}/ipv4
> ```

How do I, with only awk...
Search multiple files.
Excluded lines matching pattern.
Bring bash variable into awk.
emulate 'grep -o' using a regular expression.
sort results (care less if they're sorted just needed for 'uniq' in bash)
emulate uniq
write results to file

Input File(s) look like this

> ```
> #Comment
> http://192.168.0.1/whatever #Comment
> 192.168.0.1
> http://192.168.0.1/whatever/whatever
> 192.168.0.1 #Comment
> 192.168.0.0/16
> 192.168.0.0/16 #Comment
> ```

Output after duplicates removed...

> 192.168.0.1
>   192.168.0.0/16

**Update: 1**

Here is where I am at now...

This works exactly the way I want it too..

```
_regex_ipv4_ip_='192.168.0.1'
_regex_ipv4_cidr_='192.168.0.0/16'

awk -v exclude='#' -v include="${_regex_ipv4_ip_}" -v include2="${_regex_ipv4_cidr_}" '($0 !~ exclude) && match($0,include) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++ || match($0,include2) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++' /home/master/Desktop/t_*
```

However I can't properly carry my regular expression contained in a variable in to awk correctly.

```
_regex_ipv4_ip_='((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])'
_regex_ipv4_cidr_='(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))'
```

Comment: Is there a reason *why* to need to do that with *awk*? Does that piping you show there works for you?

Comment: What you describe is trivial in awk but show a couple of sample input files and the associated output so we can get the details right (e.g. is it unique per file or unique across all files you want)

Comment: The above piping does indeed work. I want to see if there's other code which would make the process faster considering I do this several times with different expressions and patterns. I figured awk may be a better place to start rather then piping and calling so many commands. What's happening in the code above is my expression is saved as a variable for use in other places in the script. 1.) ignore lines that begin with '#" 2.) print only the matching ip address expression or ip cidr expression. 3.) remove duplicates across all files and save result to output file.

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want is something like:

```
awk -v exclude='whatever' -v include='whatever' '
($0 !~ exclude) && match($0,include) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

but until you post sample input/output we can't fill in the details.

Comment: I am wondering if you have an answer for this: [How to print own script name in awk?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228072/40596). I cannot imagine anyone else knowing how to do this : )

Comment: `print ENVIRON["_"]` would work in some awks but idk how portable that is. As always, though, I wouldn't execute an awk script using a shebang in a shell script as it just robs you of possible functionality (e.g. the ability to use `-v` to set a command-line variable such as `awk -v cmd="$0" 'script' "$@"`). I added an answer to that question.